# Powershell; Trying to get .replace or -replace to loop through a single file and replace the same single line with something different each time

Tags: powershell

Every time I try to run this it stops at the first position and only replaces one time when I need it to replace the same line each time.

```
$kp3 = get-content -path .\Desktop\name.txt
$kp4 = get-content -path .\Desktop\source1.txt


$wk =@("wk","fa","fav")


for ($i=0;$i -le 3;$i++){

    $te = $kp3[1] #this is the position im trying to replace.

    $kp2 =  ".\Desktop\name.txt"

    $name = $wk[$i]

    (Get-Content $kp2).Replace($te,$name)|set-Content $kp2
}
```

My text file should have the "fav" in it because it is last in the array but instead it is stopping at "fa"

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me.. Where does `$kp3` come from?

Comment: HI Theo sorry i forgot to add some code.

Comment: what im trying to do is use the replace function to loop and replace a single line in my txt file multiple times. For example in my file i have 1,2,3 and im trying to replace 2 each time it loops.i have a,b and c in an array and i wanna replace the number two with each letter. each time you open the file it would look different. 1,a,3 then it would be 1,b,3 and last when you open the file it would be 1,c,3.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to replace is never updated in your loop.  We can't see what's in your file but I'm surprised it's getting to 'fa'.

You are changing the content of $kp2, but reading what to replace from $kp3, which is never updated.

Comment: Hi Brian, they are the same file which is name.txt.

Comment: what is in the file is 
Job1
Job2-im replacing this but it stops at "fa"
Job3

Comment: Yes, it is the same file.  But you read it into variable $kp3, which is now not the file, nor a link to the file.  Then you use that _variable_ to find what to replace, but you find it and replace it in a new _variable_ $kp2, which you write to and read from.  And you never refresh $kp3 with the new info you have written into the file.

Comment: So you need to move your ```$kp3 = get-content -path .\Desktop\name.txt``` inside of the loop.